# Cannot access type alias from class template definition in separate file without typing full declaration of alias type

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14, generic-programming

I have a class template like  **Sample.hpp** with type alias **X**.

```
#ifndef SAMPLE_HPP
#define SAMPLE_HPP

template<typename STA, typename STB>
class Sample
{
    using X = Sample<STA,STB>;

public:
    Sample();
    inline X* GetNext() const;

private:
    X* Next;
};

#include "Sample.cpp"

#endif // SAMPLE_HPP
```

And definitions are in **Sample.cpp**.

```
#include "Sample.hpp"

template<typename STA, typename STB>
Sample<STA,STB>::Sample() {
    Next = nullptr;
}

template<typename STA, typename STB>
typename Sample<STA,STB>::X* Sample<STA,STB>::GetNext() const {
    return this->Next;
}
```

My question is that, are there any others ways of defining **GetNext** function. For example without **typename** or without full declaration of **Sample** class template. When I change code to

```
template<typename STA, typename STB>
Sample<STA,STB>* Sample<STA,STB>::GetNext() const {
    return this->Next;
}
```

It works, but I cant use type alias here directly , for example :

```
template<typename STA, typename STB>
X* Sample<STA,STB>::GetNext() const {
    return this->Next;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use a trailing return type with the help of `auto`:

```
template<typename STA, typename STB>
auto Sample<STA, STB>::GetNext() const -> X* {
    return this->Next;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, can you please explain this in more detail?

Comment: @CherkesgillerTural Sure thing. So if you put `X*` at the start, the compiler has no way of knowing that `X` is supposed to be, so you get an error. But if you write it *after*, then the compiler can look in the scope of `Sample<STA, STB>` for `X`. If you put it before, it didn't encounter `Sample<STA, STB>` yet, so it can't look for `X` there. More information about that [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function).

Comment: Thank you very much, @Rakete111.